# Permissions in an azure function to call another one

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an azure function configured with an explicit deny for inbound traffic and I want to allow another azure function to call the first one. How should I configure the permissions to do so?

Comment: Try adding func2 Ip address in the Allow rules of func1 Access Restriction like here- https://i.imgur.com/AWOU9A5.png You can find the Inbound and Outbound Ips of your Function by clicking > Overview > right side > JSON View like here - https://i.imgur.com/M1bKVWe.png you also need to make sure both the functions are in same vnet

Comment: You can also find the Func IP address directly by visiting Networking tab refer here -https://i.imgur.com/K8ZEubF.png

Comment: Should all the outbound ips from func2 be included in the inbound rules of func1? or just one?

Comment: All the Ip's also try to allow the entire Vnet if both functions are in same Vnet like here-  https://i.imgur.com/2JDsQZy.png

Answer (score 0):

The 'easy' solution would be using messaging. Make function A add a message to a queue, which only function B will listen to.

Internally, you can extract the logic of the current function (in case it's http triggered) and make it available for the QueueTriggered too.